# Is left-aligned text generally preferable over centered text?

Tags: text, alignment

I am currently reviewing the usability of some internal reports. One thing which strikes me as odd is that all the text is centered. I always prefer left-aligned text.

But apart from my personal opinion (and also apart from design aspects): is left-aligned text preferable from a usability standpoint? (left-to-right text direction assumed).

I can imagine that the eye needs to do more work with centered text (looking for the start of the next line), but I can't find any sources to support this thesis.

Edit:
The linked "duplicate" question(s) cover the alignment of the content area of a webpage, this question is about the text. I don't think that this is the same problem.

Comment: Here's a really fresh article exactly in this topic:
[Why you should never center align paragraph text!](http://uxmovement.com/content/why-you-should-never-center-align-paragraph-text)

Comment: For clarification: Do you really mean centred text for a report, or do you mean justified?

Comment: look also: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/is-there-a-usability-reason-for-centring-a-websites-content-area-on-a-page/
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7979/websites-aligned-to-the-left-of-the-page

Comment: How is this a duplicate? He is asking about text-alignment, the other question are about the positioning of the content container... They are hardly the same.

Comment: I fully agree with @RolandStuder - thus voting to reopen this question.

Comment: I assume that this question is in the context of languages that are read from left-to-right? Or is this a more generic question covering even languages that read from right-to-left?

Comment: Yes, the original question was asked in the context of language read from left-to-right. But looking at the answer again my feeling is, that the same (or better reverse) would apply to right-to-left languages. What do you think?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I'm not going to copy everything directly, so here's a [link to a discussion on IxDA.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20150315214350/http://www.ixda.org/node/14744) on this exact topic. It has references to several research studies showing why left-aligned text is better. You are essentially right — it takes more work to read centered text when going from line to line. You are also more likely to lose your place because you don't have that anchor on the line above of text that you have already read.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This article suggests making the text more difficult to read may improve comprehension, not sure if that applies to text alignment. http://infoworld.com/t/collaboration/send-clearer-message-ugly-fuzzy-fonts-661

Comment: And it is worth noting that generally people prefer justified text, even though it slows down reading speed.

Comment: I haven't read it but I know its inaccessible for people with cognative impairments.

Comment: @Splog, People prefer reading justified text? Then I must be alien. Where did you get that from?

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now.

Comment: @Michael Updated to use archive.org version of URL.

Answer (score 8):

Charles' link looks good. Two key reasons to left align off the top of my head ...

(1) **Legibility** - easier to read, as you and Charles both point out above

(2) **Consistency** - users expect text to be left aligned - not just in digital but print formats. Only break norms to achieve a particular goal - for example, I'm not sure I would ever center text (and certainly not large bodies of text given the legibility issues) but as you point out, this both jars user expectation and requires the user to do more work in order to interpret the text, so there is the argument that in some instances this might actually be desirable - e.g. to deliberately force the user to focus on that particularly important text (such as a warning message) in order to understand why it has been given that formatting treatment.

Might also try: http://blogs.infragistics.com/ux/articles/text-treatment-and-user-experience.aspx

Comment: +1, Good pointer regarding centered text having more "focus".

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the fact that **this is how most western cultures teach people how to read**.

We start off learning left to right reading from the top down.

It's a good practice to produce & design content based on the cultural and standard norms for your target demographic.

Comment: +1, though the "western culture" is **not** the whole world's population (not even half).

Comment: @Pacerier yes, but we invented the computer. "The victors write the..." *future*, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

We can only read an area of an half inch to an inch or so before our eyeballs have to move, which involves physical effort even if it is instinctive. With text that has a vertical left-margin, our eyeballs can return to the same starting position with each new line. With centered text, the start positions of line vary and thus create extra physical/psychological strain as we locate the next line.

This limitation to our eyesight probably comes from our evolution as top-tier land-based predators; we needed sharp vision to stalk prey but we didn't need sharp vision beyond a limited central area.

Comment: Sources please.

Comment: Nah people can understand these assertions on their own; you don't need scientifically conducted research to prove or disprove everything. I know the gatekeepers of this site want to remove so-called opinions, but doing so discourages people from using their knowledge, observation, and insight to state their conclusions even if they do make sense. Limiting questions and answers to things that can only be proved or disproved by outside sources also limits the site. It also leads to what I call "intellectual laziness."

Comment: I was talking about your sources for your last paragraph... The part on evolution.

Comment: Conclusions about evolution can't actually be proved or disproved: you can't re-create millions of years, so you can only make educated guesses based on observation. Just look at the faces of every apex land-predator you can imagine; notice where the eyes are located on the head and positioned relative to each other. Maybe you don't believe in evolution, (and I'm not go to argue either way) but it can't be a coincidence these animals stalk prey mostly with their eyes. At the same time, they generally don't have to worry about attacks from the side or behind. How would this affect their vision?

Comment: When I say "sources please" I mean you should include explanations that support your assertions. Explanations can come in the form of text, or links to text. You should edit the answer to include the "text explanation" found in your last comment.

Comment: Just watch people eagerly devouring what is on their screens. Much harder if they had eyes like horses or guinea pigs. (but chameleons could look at two different screens at once) (Shh! you'll ruin the story)

Comment: @TimHuynh "I know the gatekeepers of this site want to remove so-called opinions, but doing so discourages people from using their *knowledge, observation, and insight*" I think you mean [heuristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) :)

Answer (score 1):

Also people like straight lines, we decipher linear spaces quicker than we do unbalanced spaces as it allows our eyes to move quicker down a particular path rather than searching out frequent starting points.

Applying this to a usability perspective, retention and attention spans are critical, so having core information which is difficult for the eye to comprehend is only going to annoy people and dilute the message

[See this text 4th paragraph down.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SWu4SB92fHMC&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=our%20eyes%20follow%20straight%20lines&source=bl&ots=rSkwGwnKJj&sig=P-Qg8DtPH7h10iqWumu_WHRft70&hl=en&ei=51-lTaHBEoer8AOLy8y5Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=our%20eyes%20follow%20straight%20lines&f=false)